# Last label is not showing in stepped labels of highchart

Tags: highcharts

I have a highchart which shows date label on x-axis, When there are more than 10 dates I'm using a logic of dividing the total dates by 10 and giving the resulting value to step. Because of step value it is not showing the last label. 
Please help if anybody know's the solution.
I tried with showLastLabel and endOnTick but these are not working.

```
xAxis: {
   categories: xcategories,
   labels: {
              step: getStep(chartJson.length)
           }
}

function getStep(jsonLength){
    var step =1;
    if(jsonLength>=10){
        step= (parseInt)(jsonLength/10);
    }
    return step;;
}
```

Comment: If you're using dates on the x axis, why not make it a datetime axis, and just let the chart figure out how to space the labels?

Comment: Can you please brief on your answer. On y-axis my graph shows some count.

Answer (score 2):

Set [showLastLabel](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.showLastLabel) parameter as true

Comment: This doesn't work with the step property set to an interval that leaves the last label blank (ie step:2, even number of data points):  http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/yPLVP/81/

Comment: You are right, showLastLabels works for global label, not includes step value.

Answer (score 0):

try setting max value for the xAxis. You would have to calculate last step dynamically if your categories are not fixed.
Documentation here : https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.max