# How to force Highcharts to show last label on xAxis?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, axis

It seems that in a stepped xaxis the normal "showLastLabel" [doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23518720/last-label-is-not-showing-in-stepped-labels-of-highchart). In my case, I am displaying every tenth year only; but if I want to see in any case the latest year, it doesn't work. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/grg4b6xk/4/).

```
$(function () {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(
            {
                chart:
                {
                    renderTo: "container",
                    type: "line"
                },
                title: 
                {
                    text: "Emissions of CO2 - from Fossil Fuels - Total (CDIAC)"
                },
                xAxis: 
                {
                    categories: ['1961','1962','1963','1964','1965','1966','1967','1968','1969','1970','1971','1972','1973','1974','1975','1976','1977','1978','1979','1980','1981','1982','1983','1984','1985','1986','1987','1988','1989','1990','1991','1992','1993','1994','1995','1996','1997','1998','1999','2000','2001','2002','2003','2004','2005','2006','2007','2008','2009','2010'], 
                    labels:
                    {
                        step: 10
                    },
                    showLastLabel: true,
                    endOnTick: true
                },
                yAxis: 
                {
                    min: 0
                },
                series: 
                [   {
                            data: [836290,884698,947139,970623,961804,953139,937905,986489,1053841,1027857,1039329,1043832,1088357,1065419,1005220,1094115,1055965,1082764,1121897,1104068,1052479,1019684,1015786,1037513,1048350,1051961,1036999,1033773,1017926,1014450,930734,892705,878363,866267,864817,890342,862982,856064,823133,830657,854361,829449,834088,826572,807363,809521,784657,784000,732848,745994],
                            name: "Germany"
                        }]
            });

});
```

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: You don't have data for 2011. If you add the data for 2011 it will show the label.

Comment: But I want that it shows the xaxis label for 2010, as this is the last available year.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/grg4b6xk/5/
This is the best way I could find:

```
   chart:
   {
        renderTo: "container",
        type: "line",
        events:{
             load:function(){
                 var ticks = $.map(this.axes[0].ticks, function(t){return t;});
                   ticks[ticks.length-2].render(0);
            }
         }
    }
```

Add `load` event handler. In this event handler take ticks of axes x (`axes[0]` is x and `axes[1]` is y). `ticks` is an array-like object so you need to map it to an array to access it by index. The last item in that array is some tick with position -1 so the real last tick is in position before it (so it is `length - 2`). Then call the `render` function passing a number that divides by 10. I used 0. So the tick rerenders on the last position.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that works great. However, this works only for when the categories are written into the xAxis item, as in the fiddle. In my case, I have the data being loaded from a CSV file ([here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/yhh2ca65/1/), however it does not work as it loads the CSV from an external server, which is not allowed). And in my case it just writes the last "count" of the xaxis items, which is for fifty years available "50". Do you have any idea how to access the "real" xaxis values then?

Comment: @luftikus143 if that file is static and 2011 is the last year you can add `labels: { formatter: function() { if(this.isLast) { this.value = '2011'; } return this.value; } }` into `xAxis:` object. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yhh2ca65/2/)

Comment: Thanks, but no, it's not static. I have a few hundred different variables which are being plotted, and the last year is different in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you know you want data to end on 2011, then add that category:

```
categories: ['1961', '1962', '1963', '1964', '1965', '1966', '1967', '1968', '1969', '1970', '1971', '1972', '1973', '1974', '1975', '1976', '1977', '1978', '1979', '1980', '1981', '1982', '1983', '1984', '1985', '1986', '1987', '1988', '1989', '1990', '1991', '1992', '1993', '1994', '1995', '1996', '1997', '1998', '1999', '2000', '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011']
```

Then force `xAxis` to display that label:

```
min: 0,
max: 50
```

And demo: http://jsfiddle.net/grg4b6xk/6/

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts accepts `null` values, so in your case, I appended `null` and `2011` to their respective arrays. I'd show you the 'code' but that is literally all I did, and considering the key values are JSON code...I guess there you have it. [Here's a fork of your fiddle functioning as you desired](http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/grg4b6xk/49/).