# Use the "step" label option in Highcharts, starting at the end of the xaxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts, label, axis-labels

While I was just testing my graphs again ([here is a fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/luftikus143/4pwLj5p7/1/) as an example), I realized that it would make more sense to start the xaxis step-labelling (e.g. every 10th year to be displyed) at the end and not at the beginning of the xaxis. For me as a user it makes more sense to know directly the latest year available, and not the first available year.

As I didn't yet succeed in forcing the display of the latest year, neither with

```
    endOnTick: true,
    showLastLabel: true
```

nor [with a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26467048/how-to-force-highcharts-to-show-last-label-on-xaxis), it came to me that the best way would probably anyway to force Highcharts to start counting with the latest available year.

Anyone having already done this? Or - more probably - this is not being possible?

Comment: Maybe better instead of categories, use datetime type of xAxis, and then call endOnTick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use `tickPositions` or `tickPositioner`?

You can use them to manually tell the xAxis to show labels in 20 years interval OR `latest year available` as you said:

```
tickPositioner: function () {
            var positions = [],
                tick = Math.floor(this.dataMin);

            while (tick < this.dataMax) {

                positions.push(tick);

                tick += 20;
            }

            positions.push(this.dataMax);

            return positions;
        }
```

Here's the [DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/4pwLj5p7/2/)

Comment: @Raen: Thanks. Very useful. I tried to inverse it, so that it starts counting backwards with the latest year. Seems to make more sense. It (almost) works ([fiddle here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/4pwLj5p7/3/)), but I don't know why the years appear in such a strange way. Can you help?

Comment: No problem. The reason is that you are giving the positions in the reverse order, so the chart doesn't know the exact position when starting from the end. You can `reverse` your array when returning from `tickPositioner` : http://fiddle.jshell.net/4pwLj5p7/4/